# Are admin rights required for installing an app for all users?

Tags: windows, deployment, desktop-application

I was arguing with my colleague about this topic.
There are two main question:

1. Can user (not admin) install a desktop app for all users in windows (7, 8.1, 10)?
2. Can user update this app without admin rights?

As I know, windows will request for admin rights if we are installing some desktop app for all users.

If a user doesn't have admin rights, he won't able to modify files which admin created. So, a simple user aren't able to update an app that was installed for all users.

Am I wrong?
If we want to install an app that will be for all users, do we exactly need admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install apps for all users without certain write privileges since you generally need to modify %ProgramFiles%, the "common" start menu and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to install an app. A normal user cannot write to these locations. A member of the now deprecated power-users group can install most applications for all users even though they are not a full administrator unless the installer specifically checks for administrator rights.

A non-admin user can however install patches to an app installed for all users if the .MSI is signed, this is called [User Account Control (UAC) Patching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/user-account-control--uac--patching).

Chrome and Firefox use an alternative approach with a Windows service and scheduled tasks. This also requires an administrator to perform the initial installation.